# Pyspark And Cassandra - Extracting Data Into RDD as Fields from Map Field

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I have a table with a map field with data that looks as follows from Cassandra,

```
test_id  test_map
1        {tran_id=99, tran_type=sample}
```

I am attempting to add these fields to the existing RDD that I am pulling this data from as new fields to the exact same key which would look as follows,

```
test_id  test_map                      tran_id  tran_type
1        {tran_id=99, trantype=sample} 99       sample
```

I'm able to pull the fields fine using spark context but I can't find a good method to transform this field into the RDD as expected above.

Sample Code:

```
import os 
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext("local", "test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def test_df(keys_space_name, table_name):
    table_df = sqlContext.read\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .options(table=table_name, keyspace=keys_space_name)\
        .load()
    return table_df

df_test = test_df("test", "test")
```

Then to query data I use Spark SQL in such format:

```
df_test.registerTempTable("dftest")
df = sqlContext.sql(
    """
    select * from dftest
    "
```

Comment: can you show the code how you read this data? What library are you using to get data from Cassandra?

Comment: Sure, just added the code I am using